# How do I load an openapi 3 json file as well as my controller endpoints in my application using springdocs openapi?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I'm using `implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0'`  to create a swagger page for my app, this is working fine and is picking up all my endpoints.

I also need to load an external openapi 3 json file to show the swagger documentation of another dependency in my application(Camunda)

When I add the following lines to my application.yml it's showing the Camunda swagger documentation but the endpoints of my application don't show up anymore.

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    url: /openapi.json
```

How do I combine the external documentation and the endpoints in my application, also I prefer if I can create different swagger pages for the 2